# Why do I need Docker for Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, docker, curl, debian

I am new to Laravel development, and I spent the last 5 hours trying to get a Laravel project up and running using Docker (which apparently is obligatory). Every single time I try to create a new Laravel project using the provided `curl` cmd, it says Docker is not running although it is. Literally spent the last hour browsing the internet for possible solutions, but nothing works.

Why do I have to install Docker, Debian & co on my Windows 10 machine for Laravel development?

Comment: It's not mandatory, unless you need Redis or any other ressource that is not available on Windows. Docker is recommended so you ensure to always have the right environment for your applications (the correct PHP version, the correct database version, and so on). To start developping on any operating system, you need to install PHP, MySQL  (or any other database) and run `php artisan serve` that's it

Comment: There's no requirement for Docker, not sure where you got that idea from. Docker is, literally, just a container. Anything that runs in docker can also run directly on the main o/s

Comment: Try Homestead, it's a VM solution from the makers of Laravel. Pretty easy to set up and has everything you could possibly need. Docker's good but ads complexity. Laradock may help you there.

Comment: Docker is absolutely not mandatory for running Laravel! People have been running Laravel for years without Docker, and continue to do so. Docker is just an extra option to get a dev env up and running for people who don't want to manually install and configure PHP, Apache and so on.

Comment: @ADyson I guess because he read the official documentation where in section "Getting Started on Windows" it says: _"Before we create a new Laravel application on your Windows machine, make sure to install Docker Desktop"_ on the first line. Same happened to me, in which case Docker consume all resources from my pc and it stops automatically, so I searched for alternatives and it is why I finally have arrived at this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't **need** Docker, it just (arguably) simplifies your development experience. Docker is a containerization solution where people create `images` that contain applications and packages which when deployed, provide an environment that meets their requirements. It's kind of similar to virtualization, only it works closer to the hardware so is more performant.

With Laravel the basic requirements are `PHP`, `MySQL/MariaDB`, and `Apache/Nginx`. There are other packages people frequently use alongside Laravel such as `Redis`, `RabbitMQ` & `Memcache` to name a few. Laravel `Sail` provides a wrapper around the Docker commands for starting and stopping containers (instances of Docker images) and some pre-configured environments. `Sail` currently provides images for `PHP 7.4` and `PHP 8` and `Nginx` and a choice of `RDBMS` and some other things like `Redis`.

By using `Sail`, you don't need to install and configure these things on your host system. You install `Sail` then run a few commands to install the packages you want and away you go.

Aside from simplifying the development experience, another nice added benefit is that you can create Docker environments for development and use the same image for production so you can be confident there will be no deployment issues (or at least shouldn't be!).

Again, you don't have to use Docker with Laravel. You are not missing out on anything by not using it, you just need to install and configure your environment manually on your host.

So in your scenario, if you were to not use `Sail`, you will need to install `PHP`, `Nginx` and either `MySQL` or `MariaDB` and `Composer` at a minimum. Take a look at this [`LEMP` installation](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-ubuntu-20-04) tutorial on how to go about and then watch the [Laravel 8 from Scratch](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-8-from-scratch) series (or at least the environment setup part) for things like `Composer`.

Comment: In my experience recently, Docker made working with Laravel extremely complex and difficult. In past years, Docker worked well, now it seems to be a buggy 
kludgey resource hog that's more in the way than paving the way. I think I'm gonna skip it and Sail and just go with a raw Laravel clone to my own PHP server. Anyone else's server for the repo is their own concern, it's hard enough talking coworkers or bosses into using Docker anyway, nevermind trying to get this kind of tooling synced up across workers without me doing 90% of the setup for them anyway.

Comment: Does it have to be nginx? What's the difference between nginx and apache?

Comment: @LetsPlayNebulous Sail uses the built in PHP server via `php artisan serve`. You can use which ever web server you prefer (Apache, Nginx, IIS etc.). There are plenty of good articles outlining the [differences between Apache and Nginx](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=apache+vs+nginx&ia=web) for you to read.

Comment: So why do the laravel docs say to install docker before even startign a project. miss selling or just usual laravel confusion?  ive been away for a few years,,and 2 hours later...  iam on stack lol

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use Laravel with the local server it's absolutely fine.

You can use the composer command rather than the docker command.

If you want to use the docker command, you must have to install the docker in your PC and keep it running.

Here is the composer command:

composer global require laravel/installer

To run this command, you need composer installed. Use this link to download and install composer: https://getcomposer.org/

Laravel official Link: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x#the-laravel-installer

Comment: composer is amazing and actually makes development easier, unlike my experience with Docker recently

Answer (score 3):

Interestingly, it seems that from Laravel 9 and above, they've removed the dedicated documentation section on composer installing to "Your First Laravel Project" section, right in the beginning. So you miss this entirely if you head on to the Linux or Windows install sections.
Insert your specific version or leave the version out for latest release:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel:^10.0 your_project_folder
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/installation#your-first-laravel-project